# Where do I find the Sonos API documentation that Crestron etc use?

Tags: sonos

There is some new API that some automation systems (eg Crestron) use now, where do I go for the docs for that? As I don't see any questions for it on SO, I am guessing there is another place for that too?

Answer (score 0):

I have it on good authority that Creston just uses many of the same upnp controls, that other upnp libs do.  I used soco for my Sonos control in Creston, but to be specific, here you go:
https://github.com/jishi/Jishi.Intel.SonosUPnP